# Citrix Configuration Logging Database error

Tags: citrix, xenapp

i wanted to configure the configuration logging database within XenApp 6.5.
I created the Database with proper rights (AD User with dbo Rights on this Database), configured the COM+ Sections on the Server i wanted to configure (http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272607) and after i tried to Test the connection to the Database i get an Error:

Unknown error occurred: error code 0x8200003e

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything listed in this topic: http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272607

Comment: As written -> yes

Comment: Hah, sorry! I did compare the threadID, must've looked at a different article. Ignore me :)

Answer (score 0):

Start in Administrative Tools the Component Services and expand Com+ Applications. Open the Properties of the CitrixLogServer, click to tab Security and remove the checkbox for "Enforce access checks for this application". After this change I can connect to the Log Database with corresponding user.